# jenkins build - trying to execute shell command that include ssh command

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, ssh

**Background Information**

I'm trying to get jenkins to execute the following shell commands as a part of my build process:

```
ssh root@10.111.11.11
rc-status
```

Right now it's failing with the following error message:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Ansible Repo/workspace
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url http://git.core.myinternaldomain.net/cgit/ansible.git/ # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://git.core.myinternaldomain.net/cgit/ansible.git/
 > git --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > git config --local credential.username git # timeout=10
 > git config --local credential.helper store --file=/tmp/git805322146950822569.credentials # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress http://git.myinternaldomain.net/cgit/ansible.git/ +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/dev^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/dev^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 3cf34f240632e3296793c130f4589fbceb37f5bf (refs/remotes/origin/dev)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 3cf34f240632e3296793c130f4589fbceb37f5bf
 > git rev-list 3cf34f240632e3296793c130f4589fbceb37f5bf # timeout=10
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson50385520935510733.sh
+ ssh root@10.111.11.11
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Host key verification failed.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

What I've tried so far:

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to tell me the line number in the known_hosts file that it doesn't like. 
On the same server that jenkins is running on, I can successfully ssh into  the remote server 10.111.11.11 with no errors from a command prompt.

Could it be the fact that it's trying as "anonymous" instead of my id? 
If so, how do I resolve this?  I can't see anything that allows me to specify what user to ssh as in jenkins.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the host key verification that fails, not user authentication. You can either ensure that the host key is stored in the `known_hosts` file (typically `~/.ssh` of the user the Jenkins is running as), e.g.

```
ssh-keyscan 10.111.11.11 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Or if you do not care about the security, you can disable the host key verification:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@10.111.11.11
```

**Other tips**

If I got it right, you want to run command `rc-status` on the remote host. In that case, you should use ssh remote command execution, i.e. give the command as a parameter directly to the ssh:

```
ssh root@10.111.11.11 rc-status
```

For setting up the public key authentication I will recommend using [SSH agent plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin). And if you have any further problems, it is always helpful to increase the ssh verbose level e.g. `ssh -vvv ...`

Comment: hi there. how can i know what username jenkins is running under?  sorry, this is literally day one for me with jenkins and i also stink with sys admin stuff. i am a lowly programmer trying to introduce ci

Comment: There is many ways. E.g. you can run command `whoami` in the shell step.

Comment: i think ssh-agent is exactly what i need right now. i will check it out.  thanks.